# Java SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match in android application

Tags: java, android, rest, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on an android application that uses rest services and hits my website(having SSL) for data. Also I have some other domains on the same server.

Now when I try to hit my website it is checking for other domains
e.g.

**My website :** 'abc.xyz.com'

**Other domain :** '*.mno.com'

**REST URL e.g.:** [https://abc.xyz.com/restapiservice/data/{dataid}?restkey={rest-api-key}](https://abc.xyz.com/restapiservice/data/%7Bdataid%7D?restkey=%7Brest-api-key%7D)

**Error:**

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:
>    != <*.mno.com> OR <*.mno.com>
>   OR

**Code:**

```
try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
            final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += String.format("?%s", paramString);
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**I have tried solution:**

```
        try {

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Added my part

        final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        //End my part

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

        // Set verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += String.format("?%s", paramString);
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I don't want to use it, as it might cause some security threats (I don't want to use "ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER")

Please suggest me some other alternative to this.

Comment: Is your server set up for [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)? Having multiple domains on the same server requires SNI for proper SSL/TLS support, AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this could help you.

```
private HttpURLConnection getHttpConnection(String param)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        KeyManagementException {

    URL url = new URL(URL + param);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
        SSLContext sc;
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS);
        sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        httpsConn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    }

    // set Timeout and method
    conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    conn.setRequestMethod(POST);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    return conn;
}
```